# My Shape file (.shp) isn' loading fully in Microsoft Server Data tools/Report Builder when inserting a map into a report

Tags: shapefile, dbf, reportbuilder

I have been using a shape file and the corresponding .shx and .dbf in another GIS package and the file has been loading with all the appropriate data however when I use the same file within Microsoft Server Data tools i.e. inserting a map into a new report then only some of the map data loads in.

The files I am using are the Ireland Electoral Divisions which can be found at http://census.cso.ie/censusasp/saps/boundaries/ED_SA%20Disclaimer1.htm

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to let you know the .dbf file is in the same directory

Comment: Just fixed the problem i was having it relates to "theMapLayer Collection Editor" by default it set the SpatialData - DesignerMaxRowCount to 1000 however I have over 3500 rows i changed this to 10000 and it displayed the data